# error on form ANGULAR 2 - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this error when I start the component:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'cliente' of undefined
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" formControlName="cliente" name="cliente" [(ngModel)]="usuario.cliente">
  <option [ngValue]="">Selecione</option>
  <option *ngFor="let cliente of clientes" [ngValue]="cliente" [selected]="usuario.cliente.codigo==cliente.codigo ? true : null">{{cliente.nome}}</option>              
</select>
```

this happen when I try open the component for a new data, if a load the component with a data to edit, does give me any error

Variable in TS file:

```
@Input() usuario: Usuario = new Usuario();
```

Comment: the english u used is pretty confusing.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error using plunker.

Answer (score 0):

that error is occurring because when usario is not passed in as an input the html directives

```
[(ngModel)]="usuario.cliente"
```

and

```
[selected]="usuario.cliente.codigo==cliente.codigo ? true : null"
```

are trying to use the cliente property of usuario (which in this case is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

You should only use Form or ReactiveForm don't use both.

`<select class="form-control input-lg" name="cliente" [(ngModel)]="usuario.cliente">
  <option [ngValue]="">Selecione</option>
  <option *ngFor="let cliente of clientes" [ngValue]="cliente" [selected]="usuario.cliente.codigo==cliente.codigo ? true : null">{{cliente.nome}}</option>

</select>`

@Input just use when receive value

```
@Input() usuario: Usuario = new Usuario(); is wrong
```

you can use like this:

```
@Input() _inpusuario
usuario: Usuario;
constructor(){
   this.usuario = new Usuario();
   if(this._inpusuario != null){
      this.usuario = this._inpusuario
   }
}
```